# How to keep console window open even after program started from batch-file has been terminated?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-console

I need to create a batch-file (.bat) which keeps the console window open even after the started program has terminated (for the purpose of examining the console window output). For that I tried to use the "/WAIT" switch:

```
@ECHO OFF
title test
@ECHO ON
start "" /WAIT "C:\My CLI Tools\7zip\x64\7za.exe"
```

But despite using the "/WAIT" switch the console window automatically closes after 7za.exe is terminated. (Obviously, the "/WAIT" switch waits only until the started program has been terminated).

So how can I make the console window stay open even after 7za.exe has been terminated?

Comment: `pause` at the end, or `timeout /T 300` is the only way.. /wait only tells the batch to wait for 7z to terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start /wait` tells batch to wait for the program to terminate, before performing next line, or to finish script. to keep it open and do nothing you can use pause:

```
@ECHO OFF
title test
@ECHO ON
"C:\My CLI Tools\7zip\x64\7za.exe"
pause
```

Or timeout:

```
@ECHO OFF
title test
@ECHO ON
start "" /WAIT "C:\My CLI Tools\7zip\x64\7za.exe"
timeout /t 300
```

But both these will do nothing until it either times out, or you press any key.

If you were expecting output in cmd window, and the command actually provides output to cmd console, then you should not `start` it outside of the current console window. Just do:

```
@ECHO OFF
title test
@ECHO ON
"C:\My CLI Tools\7zip\x64\7za.exe"
pause
```

Comment: But 7za.exe is supposed to output usage help txt if no switches/parameters are present. But when I use the "pause" statement at the end of the batch-file there is no usage help text output. So how can I both see the usage help text output AND keep the console window open?

Comment: @user1580348 Does it show that in a cmd window? If that is the case, try the very bottom code.

Comment: Yes, if I remove the "start """ part then it shows the usage help output in the cmd window. But what is "start """ for? Sorry for my asking.

Comment: `start /?` from cmd will explain everything, but in short, it starts the command outside on a separate cmd instance.

Comment: to understand how it acts.. open `cmd`and type `start cmd` see what happens. Then in the same `cmd` just type `cmd` and see what happens. The first will open a new window, the second runs the command in the same window.  lastly `start "" /wait` simply the 2 double quotes is to create empty title, `/wait` simply waits for the newly opened command to close, before it continues. so `start "Mywindow" /Wait cmd` will open a new cmd, but with a title of MyWindow the first cmd will be in waiting state.

Comment: I find the `start` switch `/B` very convenient, as it allows BOTH to keep using the `start` command and its switches/parameters and get the output of the program in the same console window opened by the batch file.

Comment: It's a console window, not a CMD window. I understand you may be saying this as a shorthand for a console window that's allocated by CMD or a console window that has CMD in the foreground. But it can be (and usually is) misunderstood that the console window is created by CMD. The console is an OS resource to which multiple processes can be attached. In Windows 7+ it's implemented by conhost.exe.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, thank you and I fully agree. The main reason I mention cmd and not console is that some people do not know what I am referring to as they see it as cmd... (I think because the executable is called `cmd.exe` mainly but) But you are 100% correct yes.

Comment: @eryksun Updated answer... and thanks for the upvote!